# Magento 1.9, get category tree for export

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I need to export all products and their categories into an XML file.

I've managed to get everything I need apart from the category tree, I need to import the exported data into WooCommerce so I need every category that a product is in printed out in tree, e.g:

`Products > Golf > Balls`
`Products > Golf > Balls > White`
`Sports > Golf`

I've got the following code, but it doesn't produce exactly what I need:

```
function getCategoryPath($sku)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);

    $pathArray = array();
    $collection1 = $product->getCategoryCollection()
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addAttributeToSelect('path')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');

    $i = 0;
    foreach($collection1 as $cat1){
        $pathIds = explode('/', $cat1->getPath());
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $pathIds));

        $pahtByName = '';
        foreach($collection as $cat){
            $catName = $cat->getName();
            if($catName !== 'Root Catalog') {
                if($catName !== 'Default Category') {
                    if($catName !== 'Category') {
                        $pathArray['cat_'.$i] = $catName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $i++;

    }
    $data = array_filter($pathArray, function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; });
    return $data;
```

This returns what I need, just not in the right format.